# How can I replace a list of LIKE statement in a query to optimize it?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, sql-like

I have to optimize a query with many LIKE and AND statement because the search has become very slower cause of the amount of data in tables.

I've read something about indexes and full-text indexes but I don't understand how to use them.

Here an example of the query:

```
SELECT o.* 
FROM (
        (op INNER JOIN o on op.idordine=o.idordine) 
        INNER JOIN f on f.idfornitore=o.idfornitore
    ) 
    INNER JOIN u on u.idutente=o.idutente
WHERE f.ragsoc COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%something%' 
AND u.idutente  COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%somethingelse%' 
AND o.codice  COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%something%' 
AND (o.autorizzazione  COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%somethingelse%' 
    OR o.autorizzazione2  COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%something%'
    ) 
AND (op.codice  COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%somethingelse%' 
    OR op.descrizione  COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%$something%'
    ) 
AND op.destinazione  COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%$somethingelse%' 
AND (o.data BETWEEN '$ed' AND '$ea')
```

Comment: When you are using LIKE statement on SQL query, only if you are using **'%something%'** or **'%something'** it won't use index even you have an index on that column. But it uses index for the search **'something%'**. Not sure, but I guess the COLLATE statement would also cause not using index.

Comment: A `LIKE` pattern that starts with a `%` most likely won't use an index. If you still need your patterns to start with `%`  then you need to study "full text search".

Comment: If this http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#search_multiple_columns_for_a_substring does not provide enough information, ask a more detailed question.

Comment: This may be usefull to search the same string in multiple columns. I have to search a specific string for each column and I need to respect all "filters" at the same time.